# Serial port monitoring application for Windows CE?

Tags: windows-mobile, serial-port, windows-ce

I have an application on a Windows CE device that tries to receive data over a serial port. This isn't working and now I'm looking for some simple application to run on that device that'd let me check if there is any data coming in. Is there something like HyperTerminal that let's me monitor a serial port on mobile devices?

Best would probably be an application where the source code is available, so that I can adjust it to the specifics of the device I'd like to run it on (some commonly used system DLLs are not available).

Answer (score 2):

When I was doing a lot of serial comms based work on windows mobile I found [ZTerm for PPC](http://www.tsreader.com/ztermppc/index.html) an invaluable tool. It supports a direct serial connection so you can use it to talk to serial ports, modems etc. And also supports socket based comms so you can use it as telnet to talk to remote systems.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows CE you communicate with a serial port almost the same way as you do in classic Win32. The only difference is that overlapped I/O is not supported.

So I guess it would be easy to adapt an existing C++ library to your needs. There are many articles available in [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/SerialPortComm.aspx). [This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/SerialPortComm.aspx) is one example article.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check [this](http://nah6.com/~itsme/cvs-xdadevtools/tstmodem/) out. If I'm not mistaken I used this to check COM ports functionality (I was too lazy to download it all again and check whether this is exactly the version I used...). 
It is a basic application that sends and receives data over a chosen COM port. Basic, but you can expand the functionality.